# Display Facebook photo albums and photo comments?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, gallery, facebook

I'm looking for a way to pull in photo albums from a Facebook Fan Page into a Wordpress site and have the photos open up in a Lightbox with Facebook comments.

I've found a few plugins but nothing quite like what I'm looking for and I haven't seem any with comments.

Anyone know whether this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Should be easy using the graph api http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Facebook Photo Fetcher to share all photos from my facebook fan page to wordpress(organizing by Album is not yet available). It works well except you need to refresh the code after every upload of new photos to facebook fan page, it's not automatic.

Unfortunately for me, This plugin doesn't do what I want it to do... which is to display photos from my facebook fan page that my guests are posting (I don't post many photos).